# Memory leak in org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext$ManagedEntityImpl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, memory-leaks

Getting memory leak in org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext$ManagedEntityImpl

```
At the time the leak was detected, 19323 objects existed of class
```

org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext$ManagedEntityImpl

These objects had been created at

org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext.addEntityEntry(java.lang.Object, org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityEntry):96

and were being held
in table of java.util.IdentityHashMap

```
in nonEnhancedEntityXref of org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext
    in entityEntryContext of org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext
      in persistenceContext of org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl
        in session of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder
          in value of java.util.HashMap$Entry
            in table of java.util.HashMap
              in value of java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry
                in table of java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap
                  in threadLocals of org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread
```

Please suggest if this can be resolved if we migrate to hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar .
Currently we are using hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar.?
Based on https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/767

Comment: If you can, please consider posting the key portion of the code directly in your question here rather than as an external link.

Comment: Could you detect the problem? I am having in production the same error with version 4.2.11 of Hibernate